# One-Hot-Encoding for Wide&Deep-Model and normalization by using DNNLinearCombinedClassifier

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, recommendation-engine, supervised-learning

I'm starting to use Tensorflow and read [the Whitepaper of *Wide&Deep Learning for Recommender Systems* from Cheng et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.07792) Now I have questions in two domains by using it with tensorflow like it's done in [the tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/wide_and_deep/index.html).

1. If I use categorial Columns like `tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket("education", hash_bucket_size=1000)`: Uses the model a **One-Hot-Encoding** for this feature in its back? Or can I apply a One-hot-Encoding and are there advantages of this hashing instead of One-Hot-Encoding? What's about the Hash: Do I have to set the `hash_bucket_size`to a value as high as distinct values of this feature?
2. The second question is about *normalization* of continous real-valued-features. Cheng et al. wrote that their "Continuous real-valued features are normalized to [0,1]". If I use the `tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier` will this be done automatically? Or is it up to me to implement these normalizations?

Thanks for your support!